# Introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications in R Figure Codes

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

I recently bought the following book:

- An Introduction to Statistical Learning (ISLR)
  by Daniela Witten, Gareth James, Robert Tibshirani, and Trevor Hastie (2013)

I found example R codes for the end of chapter Labs as well as the unofficial solutions to the exercises. Does anyone know where I can find R code for the figures shown throughout the book (preferably using ggplot2)? I want to compile all the R code available for this book, for practicing purpose, but do not have enough free time to reproduce the figures myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can enroll in the online course for free and all of the R Sessions are available in the 'R Sessions' tab.

https://lagunita.stanford.edu/courses/HumanitiesSciences/StatLearning/Winter2016/info